# No such file or directory

Tags: git, directory

So I’m in the process of creating a new maven project on IntelliJ

From a many google searches I saw one that said it can happen from using two screens which I am.

So to create a new project I took these steps.

- Github
- Created new repository
- Copied SSH key
- Opened terminal and wrote
- cd Documents/git/
- Git clone “pasted SSH  “
- Added a collaborator

Then went on terminal to write :

```
cd Documents/git/Summer2021_Framework/
```

`git branch` to check if I’m in & I get an error message saying : `no such file or directory`.

My folder is in the right place in documents, then git than its own folder called `Summer2021_Framework` usually it’ll be a location problem, but it is not.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> Git clone “pasted SSH  “

You are supposed to use an SSH URL, not SSH key:

```
cd Documents/git
git clone git@github.com:<you>/Summer2021_Framework
cd Summer2021_Framework
```

Then you can start working.